# Error al mover la foto a una carpeta PDO

Tags: php, html, pdo

Hola estoy intentando mover una foto a una carpeta a través de un formulario, pero esta me da el siguiente error, y el destino de ella está bien, el caso es que quiero que mueva esa foto a dicha carpeta y la inserta correctamente en la bbdd.

***Formulario***

```
<?php 
    include '../../config/conexion.php';

    try {
        $query_categorias = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM t_categorias");
        $query_categorias->execute();
        $t_categorias = $query_categorias->fetchAll();
        //print_r($t_categorias);
    } catch (PDOException $eMostrarC) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia : ".$eMostrarC->getMessage();
    }
    
    try {
         
        $query_usuarios = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM t_usuarios");
        $query_usuarios->execute();
        $t_usuarios = $query_usuarios->fetchAll();
        //print_r($t_usuarios);
    } catch (PDOException $eMostrarU) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia : ".$eMostrarU->getMessage();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Insertar Contactos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 class="insertar">Insertar Contactos</h3>
        <form action="../procesos/tabla_contactos/insertarProceso.php"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label for="categorias">Categorias</label>
        <select name="categoriaSelect">
        <?php foreach($t_categorias as $fila_c) : 
            echo '<option value="'.$fila_c['id_categoria'].'">'.$fila_c['nombre'].'</option>';
         endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <label for="usuarioAsignado">Asignar Usuario</label>
        <select name="usuarioAsignado">
        <?php foreach($t_usuarios as $fila_u) :  
            echo '<option value="'.$fila_u['id_usuarios'].'">'.$fila_u['nombre'].'</option>';
         endforeach; ?>
        </select><br>
            
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">

            <label for="apellido_1">Apellido 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_1">

            <label for="apellido_2">Apellido 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_2">

            <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefono">

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email">

            <label for="imagen">Foto</label>
            <input type="file" name="foto" size="20">

            <input type="hidden" name="insertar_contacto" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Insertar Contacto">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Proceso del formulario***

```
<?php 
    include '../../../config/Conexion.php';
    //print_r($_POST);
    if(!isset($_POST['insertar_contacto'])){
        exit();
    }

    try {
        $selectCategoria = $_POST['categoriaSelect'];
        $usuarioAsignado = $_POST['usuarioAsignado'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido_1 = $_POST['apellido_1'];
        $apellido_2 = $_POST['apellido_2'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
        $ruta="../vista_de_contactos/imagenes/".$foto;
        $archivo=$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
        $subir = move_uploaded_file($archivo,$ruta);

        //<img src="../vista_de_contactos/imagenes/2.png" alt=""> 

        $query_insertar = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO t_contactos
         (id_categoria,id_usuarios,nombre,apellido_1,apellido_2,telefono,email,foto=$ruta)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        $resultado = $query_insertar->execute([$selectCategoria,$usuarioAsignado,$nombre,
        $apellido_1,$apellido_2,$telefono,$email,$ruta]);
        

        if($resultado === true){
          header('Location: ../../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php');
        }
    } catch (PDOException $eInsertar) {
        echo "Error al ejecutar el insert <br>".$eInsertar->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

***El error***

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(vista_de_contactos/imagenes/3.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\crud\procesos\tabla_contactos\insertarProceso.php on line 19

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBF7C.tmp" to "vista_de_contactos/imagenes/3.png" in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\crud\procesos\tabla_contactos\insertarProceso.php on line 19
Error al ejecutar el insert
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=vista_de_contactos/imagenes/3.png) VALUES ('1','1','x','x','x','x',...' at line 2
```

La estructura sería esta :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Interpretando tus errores, veo que no encuentra imagen en la ruta que le estas enviando, y que tienes un error en tu query, debido a que le estas mandando como nombre de una tabla foto=vista_de_contactos/imagenes/3.png

Comment: si le quito $ruta inserta la cadena en dicha tabla pero no mueve la imagen al destino por que puede ser ?

Comment: Pasa que no encuentra esa imagen en esa ruta, como sacas la ruta??

Comment: No la encuentra por que no la sube al directorio, cuando quito la variable '"$ruta"' del insert solo inserta la ruta en la variable $ruta declarada arriba, pero esta no hace la acción de el metodo move_upload a la carpeta no encuentro como indicarselo.